# Graphs' options vs JournalArticle stylesheet

Tags: bugs, graphs-and-networks, options, stylesheet, inheritance

**Bug introduced in 10.4 and fixed in 11.0.1**

---

As noticed by [Alexei Boulbitch, below one of my answers,](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112878/vizualization-of-percolation-paths/112881#comment306557_112881) there appears to be an unexpected issue with `VertexLabels` in `JournalArticle` stylesheet:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 StyleDefinitions -> FileName[{"Article"}, "JournalArticle.nb"]]

GridGraph[{10, 10}, VertexLabels -> None]
```

[image]

Vertex labels appear despite the explicit `VertexLabels -> None` option.

When/where are those labels settings overwritten? Should I expect that?

Comment: Looks to affect only 10.4, works fine on previous versions.  Also, from what I can tell the file "JournalArticle.nb" hasn't been modified since 10.0 so the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: A work around: `GridGraph[{10, 10}, VertexLabels -> None, 
 VertexLabelStyle -> Opacity[0]]`

Comment: It happens with other stylesheets too, such as "Standard Report".  It directly affects `ClusteringTree` which is supposed to display only leaf labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Bug introduced in 10.4 and fixed in 11.0.1

---

> [...] This GridGraph behavior does appear to be a regression in Mathematica 10.4 from earlier versions. As such I will file a report with the appropriate developers so that they may investigate the issue to be fixed in a future release. [...]