# Objects - fixed properties

Tags: graphs-and-networks, properties

How do I set properties of graphs permanently? Is there any way?

For example `VertexLabels -> "Name"`.

I would like to see labels, always when I open a new notebook and I run the codes: `CycleGraph[5]`, WheelGraph[6], MyCommand[...], Graph[...], etc. I.e.: Object with Head=Graph or a function which return such an object should display labels.

I do not see any labels here (**the below Jens' answer**):
[image]

Comment: Do you mean something like this? `SetOptions[Graph, VertexLabels -> {3 -> "Name"}]` followed by any `Graph`: you'll get the same label every time, unless you override it.

Comment: No. I would like to see labels, when I open a new notebook and I run  for example `CycleGraph[5]`.

Answer (score 5):

As I mentioned in the comment, what you probably need is [`SetOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetOptions.html). For example,

```
SetOptions[CycleGraph, VertexLabels -> "Name"];

CycleGraph[5]
```

To make this work automatically, either add it to [`init.m`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/file/init.m.html), or (more portable) make the first cell above an [`InitializationCell`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InitializationCell.html).

Of course, you can do the same `SetOptions` for other commands too, not just `CycleGraph`.

Comment: I'd just [switch style sheet to journal](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/112971/5478) :)

Comment: This method doesn't work for an arbitrary graph!!!!

Comment: @ZYX the last paragraph tells you what to do.

Comment: This doesn't work for a graph, but for a command. So it doesn't work, if I write a new command or use CycleGraph[.], WhellGraph etc. (with SetOptions[Graph, VertexLabels -> "Name"];). It is useless - add to init.m all build-in and new functions, which return a graph.

Comment: @ZYX I think it's a bit like `Graphics` and `Plot`.  `Graphics` has `Axes -> False`, but the graphics produced by `Plot` has axes, because the more specific command `Plot` overrides the defaults for `Graphics`.  Similarly, `CyclicGraph` overrides `Graph`.